# pandas: how to select data based on minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas df where i want to subset data based on minutes. Here's an example of the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
'colA': ["OK", "OK", "NO", "OK"],
'colB': ["Jimmy", "Steve", "Michael", "James"],
'timeA': ["18:10", "10:20", "12:28", "16:50"],
'timeB': ["18:20", "11:30", "08:00", "16:30"]})

before = 40
after = 15
```

As you can see I have a dataframe with 2 date variables and two variables `before`and `after`.
Difference between `timeB` and `timeA` is -10mn for the first row, -70mn for the second row and +20 for the fourth row.

The `before` variable is supposed to tell how many max minutes do you allow `timeA`to be **before** `timeB`. Here, we will subset all values with -40mn maximum between `timeB` and `timeA`
It's the same thing with `after` but it's +15mn.

The goal is to let the user choose the difference range between `timeA`and `timeB`

Do you have an idea on how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: I cant understand your second condition. What do you mean 'where the difference between timeB and timeA is under 40 minutes bfore and 15 minutes after'? Maybe give an example?

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the question for the sample data you have?

Comment: sorry I edited it's now explained better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert `df['timeA']` and df['timeB'] into datetime format:

```
df['timeA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeA'], format='%H:%M')
df['timeB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeB'], format='%H:%M')
```

Calculate the difference and format it into minutes:

```
df['timeDelta'] = (df['timeB'] - df['timeA']).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

Create the condition with `np.where()`:

```
df['result'] = np.where(((df['colA'] == 'OK') & (((df['timeDelta'] <= 40) & (df['timeDelta'] >= 0)) | (df['timeDelta'] > -15) & (df['timeDelta'] < 0))), True, False)
```

Output:

```
OK  Jimmy   1900-01-01 18:10:00 1900-01-01 18:20:00 10.0    True
OK  Steve   1900-01-01 10:20:00 1900-01-01 11:30:00 70.0    False
NO  Michael 1900-01-01 12:28:00 1900-01-01 08:00:00 -268.0  False
OK  James   1900-01-01 16:50:00 1900-01-01 16:30:00 -20.0   False
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very explicit i like that!